# How to use facebook api comment pagination endpoint?

Tags: facebook, api, pagination, comments

the endpoint I'm using is

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/{comment id}/comments
```

given the the huffingtonpost url

```
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/17/malaysia-airlines-plane-cras_n_5595516.html
```

and getting the fbcomment id from from the this endpoint

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/07/17/malaysia-airlines-plane-cras_n_5595516.html
```

How do i paginate through these comments?

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/652406464844460/comments
```

It gives the 'next' url in the paging hash but visiting that url just returns the same 25 comments? Any idea whats going on or how I might get the right information on the pagination url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this goes for v1 and v2 of the graph api and i'm posting this is because it halted my project for a couple days

the current endpoint responds in order of likes. and for some reason on that url the pagination for these intermittently work. I have not figured out why.

however the pagination does work for comments if in chronological order.
i appended the filter=stream to the url and from here you can paginate

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/652406464844460/comments?filter=stream&limit=100
```

`filter=stream` will allow you to paginate through all-level comments through the `next` data hash